# How to get value of nested object of postgres jsonb column in spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jsonb, postgresql-9.4

I have used vlad mihalcea's dependency to store json value in table.

Table name: **valuation_report**
*JsonbColumn* is **parameters** attribute name in pojo is **params**

Able to get value of single object like address="Address1"

```
{"address":"Address1","nestedObj":{"firstName":"Sanjay"}}
```

To get address I've implemented specification and @Overriden Predicate method like

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ValuationReport> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb)
{
return cb.equal(cb.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String.class,root.<String>.get("params"),cb.literal(this.locale)), this.fieldToSearch);
}
```

But now i want to find value of NestedObj like nestedObj's firstName is Sanjay.

```
{"nestedObj":{"firstName":"Sanjay"}}
```

Please help me
And I've written all this with my mobile so sorry for bad format of question.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow guys please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this with @Query annotation but there's still a way to do with criteria also.
I will show my query to do this

```
@Query(value = "select vr FROM ValuationReport vr  where jsonb_extract_path_text(vr.params,:subParam ,:key)=:value")
    List<ValuationReportJSON> getEntities(@Param("subParam") String subParam,@Param("key") String key,@Param("value") String value);
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks man this query worked. Im still eager to do the same using JPA or something

Answer (score 3):

Here is your JPA specification.

```
public Specification<ValuationReport> getFirstNameSpecification(
  final String param, final String subParam, final String value) {
return (root, query, cb) ->
    cb.equal(
        cb.function(
            "jsonb_extract_path_text",
            String.class,
            root.get("params"),
            cb.literal(param),
            cb.literal(subParam)),
        value);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This HQL query works the same way for me (for simple approach).

```
public void someFunction(String searchKey){
Query query="select obj FROM ValuationReport obj where jsonb_extract_path_text(obj.params,:subParam ,:key)=:value")
Query<ValuationReportJSON> parameters=session.createQuery(query).setParameter("value",searchKey);
List<ValuationReportJSON> resultset=parameters.getResultList();
}
```

Hope it helps !